# Odoo window action to create a new product

Tags: javascript, odoo, openerp-8

I'm creating a google map module which allows a user to create a product by right-clicking the map

the right click event is caught and fires the following:

```
dispatchNewProductAction: function() {
        console.log('called dispatch action');
        this.do_action({
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            res_model: "product.template",
            views: [[false, 'form']],
            context: {}
        });
    },
```

The product form view is displayed...
How can I pass the co-ordinates into the form view?

Another question...
If I use

```
target: 'new'
```

the save button is no longer available, how can I allow the popup form to save a new product record?

Comment: Maybe you can pass the coordinates via `context`. Just an idea, I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

For viewing Save button in new target, just add

flags: {'form': {'action_buttons': true}},

to your js action.